# Get a list made up of a list of grouped items from a source list

Tags: c#, linq

So i have a source list from a database that i get like this.

```
List<FileInfo> FileInfosList = DataBase.GetFileInfoslist(LoginInfo);
```

This returns a list with about 50 rows of FileInfo type.
Each row in the list has 10 fields two are the starttime and index

```
double starttime is starttime of media
int index is a index number from 0 to 3
```

I sort the list like this

```
List<FileInfo> sortedList = FileInfos.OrderBy(s => s.StartTime).ThenBy(c => c.Index).ToList();
```

So i need to extract groups of rows out of this sorted list where the starttime matches in the 50 rows or records. There could be 1 to 4 rows in each group.
And i need to be left with a list of the groups with matching starttimes.

EG if i wanted to extract a group of rows that matches the starttime of the first row in the list i would use

```
 double starttime = sortedList[0].StartTime;
 List<FileInfo>() group = sortedList.Where(x => x.StartTime == 
 starttime).ToList();
```

but i need a way to go through the entire sorted list and get all groups with matching start time, each group could be 1 to 4 rows (its variable) with the index number staying in the sorted order of 0 to 3.
These all these groups then need to be in a master list that i can use.

so something like

```
List<FileInfo> GroupOfFileInfo = list of rows with matching starttimes from source list
```

and i want to end up with

```
List<GroupOfFileInfo> groupslist for the entire source list.
```

I hope this is clear.

thanks

Comment: check `GroupBy`

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, use .GroupBy().

GroupBy can be a little confusing to use, so here's an example console app:

```
class Program
{

    //Simple 'file info' class
    public class FileInfo
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public string OtherInfo { get; set; }
    }

    //Set up example data.
    static List<FileInfo> data = new List<FileInfo>()
    {
        new FileInfo{ Index = 0, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,01,01), OtherInfo="Item 0" },
        new FileInfo{ Index = 1, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,01,01), OtherInfo="Item 1" },
        new FileInfo{ Index = 2, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,01,01), OtherInfo="Item 2" },
        new FileInfo{ Index = 3, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,02,01), OtherInfo="Item 3" },
        new FileInfo{ Index = 4, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,02,01), OtherInfo="Item 4" },
        new FileInfo{ Index = 5, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,02,01), OtherInfo="Item 5" },
        new FileInfo{ Index = 6, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,03,01), OtherInfo="Item 6" },
        new FileInfo{ Index = 7, StartTime = new DateTime(2019,04,01), OtherInfo="Item 7" }
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //First GroupBy what you want to group by.
        var groupedList = data.GroupBy(x => x.StartTime);

        //This gives a list with the number of distinct group items.
        foreach (var groupEntry in groupedList)
        {
            //groupEntry is an IGrouping, which contains 'key' as the group key
            //(a DateTime in this case, StartTime in the source list)
            Console.WriteLine($"Items in Group : {groupEntry.Key}");
            //each item is itself an IEnumerable of the items in that group
            foreach (var groupItem in groupEntry.OrderBy(x=>x.Index))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  - Index:{groupItem.Index}; OtherInfo = {groupItem.OtherInfo}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output of the above:

```
Items in Group : 01/01/2019 00:00:00
  - Index:0; OtherInfo = Item 0
  - Index:1; OtherInfo = Item 1
  - Index:2; OtherInfo = Item 2
Items in Group : 01/02/2019 00:00:00
  - Index:3; OtherInfo = Item 3
  - Index:4; OtherInfo = Item 4
  - Index:5; OtherInfo = Item 5
Items in Group : 01/03/2019 00:00:00
  - Index:6; OtherInfo = Item 6
Items in Group : 01/04/2019 00:00:00
  - Index:7; OtherInfo = Item 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if below code helps ...

```
IEnumerable<double> gourps = fileinfosList.Select(c => c.starttime).Distinct();

var groupedList = new Dictionary<double, List<FileInfo>>();

foreach (var grp in gourps)
{
    groupedList.Add(grp, fileinfosList.Where(c => c.starttime == grp).OrderBy(d => d.index).ToList());
}
```

Comment: This would work, but .GroupBy() is a better solution, for two main reasons: 1 - it's a framework method so is optimised and is likely more efficient (in lines of code and execution time) than this approach...  2 - if this is going via an ORM (e.g. entity framework) and therefore getting translated into SQL, this approach will run a bunch of separate SQL queries, whereas the ORM will know what to do with GroupBy() and this will likely generate more efficient SQL.

Comment: incidentally, If a *dictionary* is the desired result, you could also actually do this in one statement: `var groupedList = fileinfoslist.GroupBy(f => f.StartTime).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());`

Answer (score -1):

Install the package MoreLINQ `https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/` and use the function GroupBy

Comment: you don't need MoreLINQ to use GroupBy().  It's an extension method in the System.Core Assembly in the System.Linq namespace... it's built-in.